# XML Node Attribute returning as NULL when populated?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML Doc that I'm pulling out a specific Node and all of it's attributes. In debug mode I can see that I'm getting the specific Nodes and all of their attributes. However, when I try to get the attribute value it can't find it and returns a NULL value. I've done some searching and looked at some examples and from what I can tell I should be getting the value but I'm not and I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to get the StartTime value.

Here is the XML that is returned.
[image]

Here you can see in debug and with the Text Visualizer the value should be there. 
[image]

The code I'm trying.

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("PlannedAbsences");
if (nodes != null && nodes.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {

        if (node.Attributes != null)
        {
            var nameAttribute = node.Attributes["StartTime"];
            if (nameAttribute != null)
            {
                //var startDate = nameAttribute.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're iterating over all the `PlannedAbsences` nodes in the document. The `StartTime` attribute isn't on `PlannedAbsences`, it's on `Absence`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the XDocument class contained within the System.Xml.Linq namespace, grab the sub elements from the PlannedAbsences parent, then iterate over sub elements retrieving the value of the desired attribute.

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"path to xml file")
var absences = xmlDoc.Element("PlannedAbsences")?.Elements("Absence");
foreach (var item in absences)
{
    var xElement = item.Attribute("StartTime").Value;
    Console.WriteLine(xElement);
}
```

Comment: I get 'XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'Element'.

Comment: Check that you have the System.Xml.Linq namespace added. The xmlDoc variable should be a XDocument type. I'll edit my answer to address this.

Comment: I added the System.Xml.Linq namespace and tried the updated XDocument code but I still get the same erorr "XmlDocument does not contain a definition for Element'. I'm trying to sift through the code of another project that should be calling the same end point and doing something similar to see if I missed something.

Comment: It might be worth a try using the entire namespace in the variable declaration XDocument.Load to System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load. There could be another reference with a XDocument type.

Comment: The answer suggests using `XDocument`, not `XmlDocument`. They are different classes.

Comment: Finally got it figured out. I used my original example to pull the PlannedAbsences into a XmlNodeList but that returned as a single node even though there were Absence nodes under it. I had to then create another XmlNodeList from the PlannedAbsence list to get the Absence nodes into a list I could loop through and get the attribute values. Not the prettiest but it seems to work.